# Having problems with grid css layout

Tags: css, tailwind-css, grid-layout

I am trying to achieve a grid layout using `Tailwind`, but I have troubles of implementing it.
I thought at first to use flex but I think that would be difficult to achieve.

So far I am using `grid grid-cols-3 gap-4` and it looks like the picture below, but I want the chart status to be below the *X-as* and *Lijen*, bottom to be *databak*, *algemeen* and *data/filters*.

```
   <div className="h-full grid grid-flow-col-dense col-span-3 gap-4">
      <div className="row-span-3">
         1
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-2">
         2
      </div>
      <div className="row-span-2 h-full col-span-2">
         3
      </div>
   </div>
```

I cannot make the 3 element get the remaining height..

Comment: Have you tried to make a new col and row grid within the cell where lijen sits?

Comment: does not seem to work..

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column

Basically, you want to span your cols.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
  <div class="...">01</div>
  <div class="...">02</div>
  <div class="...">03</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 ...">04</div>
  <div class="...">05</div>
  <div class="...">06</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 ...">07</div>
</div>
```

[image]

And you can do the same for the rows, so you can get Chart status in the same col under leien.

```
<div class="grid grid-rows-3 grid-flow-col gap-4">
  <div class="row-span-3 ...">01</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 ...">02</div>
  <div class="row-span-2 col-span-2 ...">03</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you replace the numbers with the text, so I can understand better how to do it?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your code added in then? Also if you follow the link you should see the examples with pictures next to it.

Comment: @kukri I added images to my answer, this should make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to just change the order of the items in the HTML?
If you're using for example a 12x12 grid you could also specify for each items the exact row/column you want it to span:

```
.grid-item-1 {
   grid-column:2/4;
}
```

You could also try `flex` - it does have the "order" property:

```
.flex-item-1 {
    order: 1;
}
```

It's not such a complex layout so you could try `flex` too.